# Change Key After Action in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

The response coming from my backend has `id` on it after adding data.
The original list contains `book_id` instead of `id` on it. How do I change the `id` to `book_id` after executing add function

**ORIGINAL LIST VALUES**

```
[{
    "f_name": "rwf",
    "m_name": null,
    "l_name": "f",
    "book_id": 12
}]
```

**NEW RESPONSE AFTER ADDING**

```
{
    "f_name": "WWW",
    "m_name": null,
    "l_name": "HHH",
    "id": 13
}
```

**ADD REDUCER CODE**

```
return {
    ...state,
    books: {
      ...state.books,
      excluded_contacts: [...state.books.excluded_contacts, action.payload],
    },
    isLoading: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like that to change the `id` to `book_id`:

```
const { id, ...props } = action.payload;
return {
  ...state,
  books: {
    ...state.books,
    excluded_contacts: [...state.books.excluded_contacts, { ...props, book_id: id }],
  },
  isLoading: true,
};
```

Comment: This `id` cause undefined on page load. `const { id, ...props } = action.payload;`